# How to get added attribute in useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

I'm using useEffect to set an attribute when a component is rendered.

```
useEffect( () => {
  if ( ! tabId ) {
    setAttributes( { tabId: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000) } ); // set random number id
  }
  console.log( tabId );
  
  // when component is removed/deleted, i will need to do something with the `tabId`
  return () => {
    console.log( tabId );
  }
}, [] );
```

The issue: `console.log( tabId )` in both cases, returns `tabId` as undefined.

Note: `setAttributes` is a function in Gutenberg to set the values. It works fine after I save the page/post and refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the added attribute in useEffect().
It is because of the order in which React hooks are called. When a component is first rendered, the useEffect() hook is called *after* the setAttributes() function is called. This means that by the time useEffect() runs, the tabId attribute has already been added to the component.

What you can do is geting it in the next render cycle.

To do this, you can use the useLayoutEffect() hook, which is called *before* the setAttributes() function is called. This means that you can get the added attribute in useLayoutEffect().

Here's how you would do it:

```js
useLayoutEffect( () => {
  if ( ! tabId ) {
    setAttributes( { tabId: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000) } ); // set random number id
  }
  console.log( tabId );
  
  // when component is removed/deleted, i will need to do something with the `tabId`
  return () => {
    console.log( tabId );
  }
}, [] );
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with `useLayoutEffect` but i get the same results.